# I am attempting the exercise on Hilbert analysis and can't wrap my head around the approach of the answer.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am doing the last part of question 5 on this [website](https://www.bibmath.net/ressources/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=bde/analyse/topologie/hilbert&type=fexo) although it is in French It can be followed easily.

The question is:
*Assume that $H=\ell^2(N,C)$, **N** and **C** being sets of natural and complex numbers resp. For a fixed integer $n$ suppose:*
$$M=\left\{x\in H;\ \sum_{k=0}^n x_k=0\right\}.$$

*Verify that M is a closed subspace of $H$. Find a subspace N such that $M\oplus N=H$
. Give the distance of the element $(1,0,0,\dots)$ from M*.

I am able to prove that M is a closed subspace of $H$ but I do not understand how to search for a complementary subspace $N$. More specifically part of their solution were they decomposed $x$ like $$x=p(x)+k(1,1,\dots,1,0,\dots).$$ From then, their answer states that taking the sum of the first $n$ terms of each member of the above expression, they find that $k=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

That is the step I do not get, my attempt was that the sum of first $n$ terms of that decomposed expression is given by: $$nx=np(x)+kn(1,1,\dots,1,0,\dots).$$

Then from here I am stuck... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the decomposition of $x$ you've found: Let $s_n:H\rightarrow\mathbb C$ be the map $$s(x_j)=\sum_{j=0}^nx_j$$(that is, $s_n(x)$ is the sum of the first $n+1$ terms in $x$). Define the map $P:H\rightarrow H$ by $$(x_j)\mapsto(x_j)-\frac{s_n(x)}{n}(1,\cdots,\underbrace{1}_{n\text{th term}},0,\cdots)$$ Prove that 1) $P$ is a projection (that is, $P^2=P$) 2) $P(x)=x$, for all $x\in M$, and 3) That $M\oplus \ker P=H$. To find $d(x,M)$, use the theorem that states $$d(x,M)=\|x-P(x)\|$$ (that is, the distance between a point and a closed subspace is equal to the distance between the point and its projection).

This is pretty standard. If you have a closed subspace $Y$, try and look for the corresponding projection $P$. Although it's not always easy, sometimes it's immediate how to project by the way the subspace $Y$ is defined, for example, if I gave you $$M=\{(x_j)|x_0=x_1=\cdots=x_n=0\}$$ the projection is (clearly, I think) $(x_j)\mapsto(0,\cdots,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\cdots)$

Comment: I kind of follow your explanation, but I do not get where the summation of each member up to $n$ of the decomposed allows us to get $k=\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: It doesn't. If you take $$x=p(x)+k(1,\cdots,1,0,0\cdots)$$ I assume you want $p(x)\in M$, so if you take the sum of the first $n$ terms you get on the left $x_0+\cdots+x_n$, while on the right you get $(n+1)k$, so the right value for $k$ is $$k=\frac{x_0+\cdots+x_n}{n+1}$$

Comment: How do we get $(n+1)k$ on the right side, are we not supposed to get a vector?

Comment: Also I think $k=\frac{x_0+\cdots+x_n}{n+1}$ becomes $k=\frac{1}{n+1}$ since $x_0$ is 0 by taking $x$ from the question as $(1,0,...,0)$ Isn't it the case?

Comment: @Fnechz, I'm taking the identity between sequences $x=p(x)+k(1,\cdots,1,0,0,\cdots)$ for a generic $x\in H$ and adding the sum of the terms in the successions up to index $n$, so on the left I'm adding the first $n+1$ terms of $x$, while in the right the sum of the first $n+1$ terms of $p(x)$ is zero, so you only have $(n+1)k$

Comment: I see your approach that generalises for $x\in H$. I now get it!